# Javascript bitwsie operation 0 ^ 2147483648 yields -2147483648

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I've ran this code in Chrome:

```
var b = 0;
console.log("b=" + b);
console.log("b bin " + b.toString(2));
var pm = 8 ;
console.log("pm=" + pm);
console.log("pm bin " + pm.toString(2));
b = b ^ pm;
console.log("b=" + b);
console.log("b bin " + b.toString(2));
console.log("_______________________________");

b = 0;
console.log("b=" + b);
console.log("b bin " + b.toString(2));
pm = 16;
console.log("pm=" + pm);
console.log("pm bin " + pm.toString(2));
b = b ^ pm;
console.log("b=" + b);
console.log("b bin " + b.toString(2));
console.log("_______________________________");

b = 0;
console.log("b=" + b);
console.log("b bin " + b.toString(2));
pm = 2147483648;
console.log("pm=" + pm);
console.log("pm bin " + pm.toString(2));
b = b ^ pm;
console.log("b=" + b);
console.log("b bin " + b.toString(2));
console.log("_______________________________");
```

console output is:

```
b=0                 
b bin 0                 
pm=8                
pm bin 1000 
b=8             
b bin 1000      
______________________
b=0             
b bin 0             
pm=16           
pm bin 10000        
b=16            
b bin 10000             
_______________________________         
b=0             
b bin 0             
pm=2147483648           
pm bin 10000000000000000000000000000000                 
b=-2147483648               
b bin -10000000000000000000000000000000             
_______________________________
```

Why doesn't b ^ 2147483648 return 2147483648 (but instead it's -2147483648) analogously to what happens with b ^ 8 and b ^ 16 ?

tl;dr:

I'm asking because I'm trying to store a 4x8 board of elements' positions, and I use bit masks to set  an element on a certain position, but for my element at (0, 0) with corresponding bit mask of 1 followed by 31 0s (decimal 2147483648)  the application of said mask to the number holding the positions makes the number turn negative.

Comment: Almost all bitwise operators in JS convert their operand to signed 32-bit integer. Since you're out of that range, it wraps around.

Comment: @cookiemonster: "Almost"? I believe you, so for my education (I'm *constantly* learning stuff here on SO): Which ones don't?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Far as I remember, the one exception is `>>>`, which is the unsigned 32-bit version of `>>`. I don't believe there are any others, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @cookiemonster: [Sure enough](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.3), thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't `b ^ 2147483648` return `2147483648` (but instead it's `-2147483648`) analogously to what happens with `b ^ 8` and `b ^ 16`...?

Because JavaScript's [binary bitwise operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10) are (nearly all) defined in terms of [*signed* 32-bit integer values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5). (The exception being `>>>`.) JavaScript's numbers are inherently IEEE-754 double-precision floating point, but the bitwise operators convert them to signed 32-bit integers and back again for the purposes of applying the operator. Since 2147483648 is outside the signed 32-bit range, it wraps.

Comment: Google: this is the correct answer for "why does 128 << 24 result in -2147483648". Workaround: replace `byte << 24` with `byte * (1 << 24)`.